# Bad Unary operand apparently

Tags: python, debugging

I'm currently making a text game, but part of my game won't work, and I can't figure out why. This is the coding:

```
c1pp1 = ["Joe", "Frank", "Annie"]

while cp_ptt < 3:
        s= input()
        #FIX THIS!!
        c1pp = input(n/ + ": Who should I talk to first?\nYour options are:\n" +\
               c1pp1[0] + ", an ex-policeman\n" + c1pp1[1] + ", a carpenter\n" +\
               c1pp1[2] + ", an architect\n")
```

The outcome I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "N:\MyWork\Year 9\Other\Random\Making a text game out of song lyrics\No.1;  
Phantom Thief F's Scenario ~Mystery of the Missing Diamond~.py", line 103,  
in <module>
c1pp = input(n/ + ": Who should I talk to first?\nYour options are:\n" + c1pp1[0] + ", an ex-policeman\n" + c1pp1[1] + ", a carpenter\n" + c1pp1[2] + ", an architect\n")  
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Is that `n/` a typo? It clearly looks like that's the problem. What are you trying to do with that?

Comment: @CarlesMitjans The error would be `NameError: name 'n' is not defined`.

Comment: Te question is: why is that `n` there? Is that a variable or did you try to print a line feed?

Answer (score 1):

Some parentheses to highlight the expression will help.

Your code is trying to parse `n / (+ ": Who should I talk to first?\nYour options are:\n")` but `+ "any string"` is not a valid use of the unary `+` operator.

Like others have pointed out in the comments, you've probably made a typo. Without the rest of your code, I can't tell you what you need to do to get your desired output, but you can probably start by removing that `/`.